# MySQL - querying average row length

Tags: mysql, row, metadata, information-schema

I have a table named rabbits. I am trying to find the average row length in my table. I tried this query:

```
SELECT AVG_ROW_LENGTH(rabbits)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please explain how it is failing. Also what database are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My Googling has indicated that `AVG_ROW_LENGTH` is actually a column in information_schema.tables.  You'll want to try something like this, I think:

```
SELECT AVG_ROW_LENGTH FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'rabbits';
```

You may also need to specify the database name by adding "AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'databasename';"  if you have more than one database with a rabbits table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll give you the upvote for beating me by 10 seconds ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can't SELECT that, try this instead:

```
SELECT Avg_row_length FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='rabbits';
```